# Taskbar running-program icon rightclick broken for Razer Synapse Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, right-click, razer-mouse, razer-keyboard

For some reason - and this doesn't happen for anything else - when I right click on my Razer Synapse icon on the little program tray at the bottom right of my taskbar, it brings up a menu which doesn't respond. What I mean by this, is it shows up, but I can't click on it or close it, it just becomes a burden and sits there until I restart my computer. I've tried refreshing the Windows Explorer task, and I've tried ending the Synapse task. It just sits there and loads.

On the other hand, this is the only way to open Synapse. I've tried force closing and re-opening the app, but it still just sits there. I have no way of accessing the program now, and I need to because I want to disable Razer Surround Sound, as it's broken and I can't hear anything when my computer says it's outputting sound to the controller / driver. Also, Surround doesn't show up on the right-click menu. Other than this, my Synapse seems to be working fine, as my macros and chroma are working perfectly.

Any help?

Comment: Uninstall the application, it's not required, for the basic operation of the device

Comment: I would like to keep the program, but I do want to fix this problem. Would reinstalling the program likely fix it?

Comment: @CamdenRichter why not give it a try? In theory, it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for an update if not then reinstalling may solve this solve the issue. If not sounds like an update issue with the software itself. Technically you don't actually need this for basic operation of the machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked my current installation's registry, deleted an old one, went into my Programs and Features, uninstalled Surround, and boom Synapse has an update. It's all good now.